# grub-install : error: unable to identify a filesystem in hostdisk//dev/sdb error seen in MAAS UI console while deploying a node

Tags: juju, maas, disk

I have configured a MAAS setup(version 1.9.4) for VM's. For one of the nodes I have attached 32GB disk (`/dev/sdb`). I am trying to deploy a juju charm which makes use of this storage ie `/dev/sdb`. When the node is getting deployed, I see that it fails with status as `"Failed Deployment"`. In the logs I see the below error :

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install : error: unable to identify a filesystem in hostdisk//dev/sdb; safety check cant be performed
failed to install grub!
Command: ['install-grub', 'tmp/tmpqwTtyG/target', '/dev/sdb]'
```

Can anyone please help me on this?